# Phonegap: Test connectivity to a specific domain/server

Tags: networking, cordova, connection

I'm building a phonegap application and I need to check network connectivity *to a specific domain*.

I searched and found [`network.isReachable`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/0.9.6/phonegap_network_network.md.html) but it's now deprecated, replaced by the [`connection`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html) object. However, the `connection` object doesn't seem to test against a specific domain; it simply gives details about the type of connectivity that the device has.

Does phonegap provide a way to check connectivity to a specific domain, or server, or is it now necessary to do an AJAX request to determine this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX should work just fine. The network object is gone and the connection object is just for determining the network status of the device.

In jQuery

```
var isReachable = false;
$.get( "my/test/domain" )
    .done( function(){ isReachable = true; } )
    .fail( function(){ /* throw error or whatever*/ } );
```